# When I must use final declaration

Tags: java, android

I wrote the next android code. The variable position must be declared as final. I do not understand  why... when I use the Eclipse debugger, it does recognize the value of position in line : myMovieList.remove(position); ?

I will appreciate your help with this issue.
Teddy

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

  .......
  .......
  .......
}



@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        showDeleteDialog(position);
    }

    private void showDeleteDialog(final int position) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete  ??");
        builder.setMessage("Are you shure....");
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                myMovieList.remove(position);
                 objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

Comment: `position` must be `final` because you are referencing it from an anonymous inner class (the one that you are using for the positive button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write something like:

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            myMovieList.remove(position);
            objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

This is called an **anonymous inner class** (the `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... }` part), because you implicitly create a class extending `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` (and overriding methods) without a name.

This anonymous inner class uses `position`, which is out of its scope, so it needs to store it in some way. This is why it needs to know that `position` won't change between the moment you declare this anonymous class, and the moment the code will indeed be executed.

With the `final` keyword, you prove that this variable won't change, and therefore you allow the anonymous inner class to store `position`'s current value internally, without risking to be out of sync later.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed my code so I can see the value of variable position via variable myPosition using the debugger : {
     
    int myPosition;
    myPosition = position;
    myMovieList.remove(myPosition);